# What's the following used font?

Tags: fonts

What's the following used font? 
[image: What's the following used font?]

Comment: Which font?  There are at least two different ones in that sample.

Comment: I need all of them, but specially the "Conception" 's font :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the pdf file with arcobat reader (Edit->Preferences->Fonts) or with `pdffonts <file>.pdf` (Linux)

Comment: when trying pdffonts myfile.pdf I get many line like this: 
name                 type              emb sub uni object ID
-------------------- ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
[none]               Type 3            yes no  no       8  0
QRGJOV+CMMI12        Type 1            yes yes no      11  0

how can I read them?

Comment: that is computer Modern Math Italic (CMMI)